# Err:6 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/debian DISTRO/main amd64 Packages 404 Not Found

Tags: kali-linux, wine

After adding new repository to install WineHQ on kali-linux and update it

```
# sudo apt-get update

> Err:6 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/debian DISTRO/main amd64
> Packages   404  Not Found

W: The repository 'https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/debian DISTRO Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: Failed to fetch https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/debian/dists/DISTRO/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

the repo is :

```
deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main non-free
deb http://repo.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main contrib non-free
deb-src http://repo.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main contrib non-free

deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-dev main contrib non-free
deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-dev main/debian-installer
deb-src http://http.kali.org/kali kali-dev main contrib non-free 

deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/debian/ DISTRO main
deb http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/ oldstable main
```

Answer (score 1):

You should not put `DISTRO` into the url there, rather put the name of the version number that you want, that is put one of `avlinux`, `jessie`, `sid`, `stretch` or `wheezy`. I am not sure which one it is that you need since you run Kali. My understanding is that Kali is based on Debian testing so you should try to put `stretch` into the url instead of `DISTRO`.

Using repos from external sources is not recommended with the Kali distribution, to install Wine your `/etc/apt/sources.list` should contain the following lines and nothing else:

```
deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali main non-free contrib
deb-src http://http.kali.org/kali kali main non-free contrib 
deb http://security.kali.org/kali-security kali/updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://security.kali.org/kali-security kali/updates main contrib non-free
```

When that file is like that, then do the following:

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install wine-bin:i386
```

It is very important that the file `/etc/apt/sources.list` contains nothing else but the above lines.

Comment: how about this sir.. deb http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/ oldstable main

Comment: Hmm, that does not seem right. Please do as GAD3R suggested and edit your question and put the content of `/etc/apt/sources.list` in the post.

Comment: Remove the last line that contains `deb http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian oldstable main`. The line that says `deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/debian/` has a typo in it, you type `stetch`, but it should be `stretch`. Then it should work. But according to Kali documentation that this is not advised, see [this](http://docs.kali.org/general-use/kali-linux-sources-list-repositories). How to install Wine in Kali is explained [here](https://forums.kali.org/showthread.php?25175-install-wine-on-kali-64bit-with-no-problems).

Comment: You should also not have the `kali-dev` lines in there, unless you are absolutely sure of what you are doing.

Comment: i just changed my repository based on kali 2016.2 new repo.

Comment: i tried to follow the instructions on your link . but when i apt-get update it 
.i got this . 
W: The repository 'http://http.kali.org/kali kali Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: The repository 'http://security.kali.org/kali-security kali/updates Release' does not have a Release file.

Comment: and this .. 
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: Failed to fetch http://http.kali.org/kali/dists/kali/contrib/source/Sources  404  Not Found
E: Failed to fetch http://security.kali.org/kali-security/dists/kali/updates/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

Comment: See the edit to my answer, does your `sources.list` file contain just those lines and nothing else?

Comment: yes it replaces all my repositories.